# I can't find the solution so that angular can access some of my files

Tags: html, angular, angular-material

I am in the process of developing a login page for an authorization management application, the problem that arises is that angular is not able to access some of my files.

here are the errors i get:

[image: Error]

however I specified the path of the files as I did for example here :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../assets/fonts/poppins/Poppins-Bold.ttf">
```

but it doesn't work.

here is the location of my files :

[image: location files]

and here is all my code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Login V1</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<!--===============================================================================================-->  
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="assets/images/icons/favicon.ico"/>
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/fonts/font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../assets/fonts/poppins/Poppins-Bold.ttf">
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/vendor/animate/animate.css">
<!--===============================================================================================-->  
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/vendor/css-hamburgers/hamburgers.min.css">
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/vendor/select2/select2.min.css">
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/util.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/main.css">
<!--===============================================================================================-->

</head>
<body>

    <div class="limiter">
        <div class="container-login100">
            <div class="wrap-login100">
                <div class="login100-pic js-tilt" data-tilt>
                    <img src="assets/images/img-01.png" alt="IMG">
                </div>

                <form class="login100-form validate-form">
                    <span class="login100-form-title">
                        Member Login
                    </span>

                    <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate = "Valid email is required: ex@abc.xyz">
                        <input class="input100" type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email">
                        <span class="focus-input100"></span>
                        <span class="symbol-input100">
                            <i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        </span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate = "Password is required">
                        <input class="input100" type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Password">
                        <span class="focus-input100"></span>
                        <span class="symbol-input100">
                            <i class="fa fa-lock" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        </span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="container-login100-form-btn">
                        <button class="login100-form-btn">
                            Login
                        </button>
                    </div>

                    <div class="text-center p-t-12">
                        <span class="txt1">
                            Forgot
                        </span>
                        <a class="txt2" href="#">
                            Username / Password?
                        </a>
                    </div>

                    <div class="text-center p-t-136">
                        <a class="txt2" href="#">
                            Create your Account
                            <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right m-l-5" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>




<!--===============================================================================================-->  
    <script src="assets/vendor/jquery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <script src="assets/vendor/bootstrap/js/popper.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <script src="assets/vendor/select2/select2.min.js"></script>
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <script src="assets/vendor/tilt/tilt.jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script >
        $('.js-tilt').tilt({
            scale: 1.1
        })
    </script>
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <script src="assets/js/main.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

can someone please help me? and thank you in advance for your precious help !!

Comment: Where is your angular.json? Also... DON"T USE JQUERY!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a relative path from the assets folder.

For example if you put the file in src/assets/css/xyz.css, then I have to access it like this :

```
< link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/xyz.css">
```

But we are talking about ttf. Your ttf is used in a css or scss like this:

```
@font-face {
  font-family:"Poppins-Bold";
  src: url("assets/fonts/poppins/Poppins-Bold.ttf") format("truetype");
}
```

This path must be relative to the resulting css. If you use scss, then the resulting css is in root, so the relative path begins with 'assets/...'.

If you include css in index.html with this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/main.css">
```

and the font-face css code is in this file, then the relative should look like this:

```
@font-face {
  font-family:"Poppins-Bold";
  src: url("../fonts/poppins/Poppins-Bold.ttf") format("truetype");
}
```